# Parent div height grow with the growt of its children whern browser resize

Tags: html, css, height

I have a div with tri-div child aligned horizontally. When the browser width chenge, one of this div goes under the other two. When the browser width is lesser the three div's are aligned vertically. Here are some images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liu0o.png)

here is the html code:

```
<div id="tribox">
        <div id = "boxweb">
            <img src="../media/img/web.png">
              <p id = "title"><b>Siti Web</b><br/></p>
              <p id = "contenent">Figlio della maestra Franca Murolo e dell'operaio Giovanni Salvemini[5] che suonava in un gruppo musicale, Salvemini cominciò a cantare da bambino. Studiò ragioneria presso l'istituto tecnico di Molfetta, sebbene avesse voluto fare il fumettista. Ottenuto il diploma, decise di occuparsi di pubblicità e vinse una borsa di studio per l'Accademia di Comunicazione</p>
        </div>


        <div id = "boxsocial">
            <img src="../media/img/socialmedia.png" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;">
              <p id = "title"><b>Social Media</b><br/></p>
              <p id = "contenent">Figlio della maestra Franca Murolo e dell'operaio Giovanni Salvemini[5] che suonava in un gruppo musicale, Salvemini cominciò a cantare da bambino. Studiò ragioneria presso l'istituto tecnico di Molfetta, sebbene avesse voluto fare il fumettista. Ottenuto il diploma, decise di occuparsi di pubblicità e vinse una borsa di studio per l'Accademia di Comunicazione</p>

        </div>

        <div id = "boxapp">
            <img src="../media/img/app.png">
              <p id = "title"><b>Applicazioni</b><br/></p>
              <p id = "contenent">Figlio della maestra Franca Murolo e dell'operaio Giovanni Salvemini[5] che suonava in un gruppo musicale, Salvemini cominciò a cantare da bambino. Studiò ragioneria presso l'istituto tecnico di Molfetta, sebbene avesse voluto fare il fumettista. Ottenuto il diploma, decise di occuparsi di pubblicità e vinse una borsa di studio per l'Accademia di Comunicazione</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
#tribox{
width:1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;
text-align:center;

}

#boxsocial{
float: left;
width:400px;
text-align: center;}

    #boxsocial img{
        left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 5px;
 }


#boxweb{
display: inline-block;
width:400px;
text-align: center;}

    #boxweb img{
        left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 5px;
  }

 #boxapp{
float: right;
width:400px;
text-align: center;}

    #boxapp img{
        left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

The problem is that under this div, i have another div:

```
<div id ="secondbody">

</div>
```

Css:

```
#secondbody {
position: relative;
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #22a1c4;
}
```

When i resize the browser the second div goes over the first div, this because the heigth of the first div doesn't change. How can i do that the second div is always under the first div?

At this moment i have used the @Media function with specific width range, but this solutions isn't elegant and efficent IMHO.
Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it with flexbox?

you put the two principal div in one div and do `display:flex;` and  flex-`direction: column;`

https://jsfiddle.net/wbo9uyb9/

```css
.test{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.treebox{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
  
}

.box1{
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
  color:red;
}
.box2{
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
  color:green;
}
.box3{
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
  color:blue;
}
.lastbox {
position: relative;
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #22a1c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

<div class="treebox">
  <div class="box1">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
              <p id = "title"><b>Applicazioni</b><br/></p>
              <p id = "contenent">Figlio della maestra Franca Murolo e dell'operaio Giovanni Salvemini[5] che suonava in un gruppo musicale, Salvemini cominciò a cantare da bambino. Studiò ragioneria presso l'istituto tecnico di Molfetta, sebbene avesse voluto fare il fumettista. Ottenuto il diploma, decise di occuparsi di pubblicità e vinse una borsa di studio per l'Accademia di Comunicazione</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
              <p id = "title"><b>Applicazioni</b><br/></p>
              <p id = "contenent">Figlio della maestra Franca Murolo e dell'operaio Giovanni Salvemini[5] che suonava in un gruppo musicale, Salvemini cominciò a cantare da bambino. Studiò ragioneria presso l'istituto tecnico di Molfetta, sebbene avesse voluto fare il fumettista. Ottenuto il diploma, decise di occuparsi di pubblicità e vinse una borsa di studio per l'Accademia di Comunicazione</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
              <p id = "title"><b>Applicazioni</b><br/></p>
              <p id = "contenent">Figlio della maestra Franca Murolo e dell'operaio Giovanni Salvemini[5] che suonava in un gruppo musicale, Salvemini cominciò a cantare da bambino. Studiò ragioneria presso l'istituto tecnico di Molfetta, sebbene avesse voluto fare il fumettista. Ottenuto il diploma, decise di occuparsi di pubblicità e vinse una borsa di studio per l'Accademia di Comunicazione</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lastbox">
  
  </div>
```